# Convert Image to CMYK and split the channels in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am trying to find a way how to convert an image into CMYK in OpenCV.
By default the images are BGR I think, so converting to a Gray image would be `img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`  but there is no `cv2.COLOR_BGR2CMYK`.
I found out with `PIL` you can do it, but no way in OpenCV?

I need to split then basically like `(C, M, Y, K) = cv2.split(image)`. Is there a way like that?

In Pillow I can do like that

```
im = Image.fromarray(np.array(image))
im = im.convert('CMYK')
c_im, m_im, y_im, k_im = im.split()
```

Comment: there is no ```cv2.COLOR_BGR2CMYK```, but you can try to convert it by yourself. Just googled it and the first link: https://code.adonline.id.au/cmyk-in-python/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either import `PIL` and convert the image from BGR to CMYK, or do it in openCV in a more "analytical" way.

From the known relations between BGR and CMYK, you can write a code like this:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 bgr = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg') #your bgr image

 bgrdash = bgr.astype(np.float)/255.

 K = 1 - np.max(bgrdash, axis=2)

 C = (1-bgrdash[...,2] - K)/(1-K)

 M = (1-bgrdash[...,1] - K)/(1-K)

 Y = (1-bgrdash[...,0] - K)/(1-K)
```

So that you can have your CMYK splitted channels. To convert your BGR to CMYK:

```
 CMYK = (np.dstack((C,M,Y,K)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks! One question why I do I have to divide by 255? And what are the three dots? It's like the spread operator in JS?

Comment: /255 because value range of 0 to 1 makes the math easier -- `...` when indexing a numpy array... is numpy-specific. it's for when you want to all-slice however many dimensions would go there

Comment: I would also recommend `B,G,R = cv.split(bgrdash)` and working with those variables in the equations for C,M,Y. makes them cleaner.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz replied for me.

Comment: AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2

Comment: K = 1 - np.max(bgrdash, axis=2) This line returns error. axis=2 is incorrect. What could be the reason?